# What should we do with questions regarding paid libraries?

Tags: discussion

I answered a question about [Revolution Slider](https://www.sliderrevolution.com/) today, which is a library that you must buy to use.

Obviously I didn't pay for it, just to be able to test it and solve the issue locally. So I went to the site that the asker linked as a reference and "pirated" the library from the Chrome Devtools sources.

My first question is, if this is something that is generally allowed? Like even outside of SO, I wonder if it's illegal to download some paid library source from a website that uses it, and play around with it locally? *(sorry this one is technically out of the scope of meta discussion, but I think it has a lot of relevance here)*

And my second question is that even if downloading the source to play around with it locally is legal in general, what does SO think about questions regarding paid libraries? I am mainly wondering if SO's policy is something like "don't answer, but leave a comment that the question should be directed at the <paid library> support"?

Comment: There are a zillion questions on Stack Overflow related to paid software. I don't see how this is any different. What matters is whether the question is on-topic or not. The fact that a piece of software being used is paid or not is irrelevant.

Comment: If it's a on topic Q, then whether the library is paid or not is irrelevant.

Comment: The first part of this feels like a legality question, which I doubt anyone on meta is going to really be in a position to answer. For the second, legality isn't relevant (someone answering the question might own it too); if you can or want to answer the question you can do so. If the question is about paid software or not isn't relevant, as SMEs for said software will exist.

Comment: Seems like this is obvious to everyone but me then. I just wanted to be sure, since I've seen large discussions about code licensing (e.g. why you should use the built-in editor instead of jsfiddle) and because my thought process was that SO allowing people to answer to questions about paid libraries could technically imply that SO encourages what I did in this case for example, as it is in no way sensible to think that someone would spend money to answer a question. Sure someone might have a license of their own, but the intersection of license owners and question answerers is probably small.

Comment: *"but the intersection of license owners and question answerers is probably small"* if it is that small, the OP (of the question) may find they need to bounty the question, or perhaps they end up contacting the support team for the library (though for such a scenario, I would have expected that to be their first port of call, not [so]). if the latter, hopefully they end up self answering so that [so] ends up with the answer too.

Comment: Answering legal questions is a huge disservice, unless you happen to find a lawyer who is also a programmer. The uninitiated (probably 99.99999% of all of us) should not try. If you get it wrong, the aftermath can be damaging. Don't do it on the main site, don't do it on meta.

Comment: _"but the intersection of license owners and question answerers is probably small"_ Maybe it is in this particular case (is it?) but it's definitely not always the case. Take Microsoft products, for example (Windows, Office, Visual Studio Professional, etc.) - Those are all paid software and we have many programming-related questions about them on SO (and non-programming-related ones on other sites, like SuperUser).

Comment: "*Obviously I didn't pay for it, just to be able to test it and solve the issue locally*" also you didn't really need to do that, either since your answer just points at the documentation. Which isn't to say that you shouldn't have posted the answer - just that it seems answerable without needing to have a copy locally. Which in turn gives you a hint at whether questions about paid technology are allowed - sure, why not? They can be answerable without needing access to the tech. And even if access is needed, maybe users can still answer.

Comment: In general, a question's on-topicness is not determined by how accessible to answering it is. There can be free but niche library, or language, or other technology. It doesn't become off-topic because it is niche or has few users.

Comment: @VLAZ The documentation was actually relatively annoying to find and even more annoying to read. I guess it's a matter of preference, but I like to always test and be very sure that what I am proposing is working, don't want to trust the documentation alone.

Comment: I hear that, I've spent three days experimenting with MongoDB indexes because the documentation is... lacking. If you just do what the documentation says you *can* do, you end up with indexes that take up 500gb of space and go into swap, tanking the performance of your stack. Just because you can do something (like put indexes on arrays of complex subdocuments), does not imply you should do it. People who are willing to prove and document what you should not do are few and far between. This is why I like Stack Overflow, people dare to go one step beyond.

Comment: The fact that there aren't many paid users on SO isn't relevant to whether it's on-topic or not. SO doesn't have a popularity threshold for topics.

Comment: I think reading poor documentation may be a better way to hone your programming skills and prepare yourself for a rewarding career in software than solving problems at Leetcode and friends. You'll be doing a lot more of it than figuring out how to implement Esoteric's Algorithm in O(log(n).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two parts in your question<sup>*</sup>:

- are questions about paid libraries/software on-topic (yes)
- what you should do when you see those (it is always ok to skip)

Yes, questions involving paid libraries/software can be on-topic. As long as the question is related to code and contains enough information for user of such product to understand (or reproduce) the issue such questions are ok. Depending on number of people who have access to the product SO may not be the best channel to ask questions in terms of getting big enough audience to get answers, but it is *not a wrong place* to ask those questions.

Note that MRE (as well as explanations) in the question should be usable for people familiar with the subject of the question. Code in the question is not to teach everyone how to use the tool/library from scratch nor be immediately usable by random person from the street. It is perfectly fine to show code for some AutoCAD script and skip all the steps to obtain, install and configure it - if one is familiar with AutoCAD they don't need any extra steps to get script working.

What you, as a person who tries to answer questions should do:

- check if question is readable in general and *someone* may be able to understand it (basic VTC/vote-up/vote-down activity)
- if you are confident enough that you *know* the right answer - write it. This is ideal case that SO is targeting for - experts in the given subject quickly provide correct and complete answers (as a perfect example look at answers by Jon Skeet - almost instant, well written, yet to contain any flaws).
- if you don't know the answer but still want to answer - figure out what you need for investigation and allocate necessary resources. This includes time, money, licenses and making sure resulting content is licensable as CC by-SA. At this point you may decide to skip the question and it is *perfectly fine* not to answer every single question. From SO point of view, it is significantly better if you answer 10 questions where you are an expert vs. investigating one where you want to learn something - that not necessarily align with benefits for you, but don't feel obligated to answer all of them.

---

<sub><sup>*</sup>Indeed I'm ignoring the third - "is it ok to steal" - part. Such question is not suitable for SO or meta, but if you have to ask it probably not ok.</sub>

Comment: Thank you! I feel like this answer was very extensive and covered everything I had trouble with.

Answer (score 7):

The "paid library" aspect is only indirectly relevant in terms of whether or not these questions are allowed here.

If the question includes all of the information necessary for it to be answered, it's on topic. If it doesn't, we have a close reason for that. If the documentation is behind a paywall, the OP should be expected to provide the parts necessary to understand their problem. Licensing being in place that forbids doing so isn't our problem and shouldn't stop us from closing a question that doesn't provide the necessary information.